# AWS CloudWatch, setting up alarm on against a metric dimension

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudwatch

I have a custom `metric` with many `dimensions`. Can I setup an alarm against the value of a `dimension` instead of the `metric`?

Comment: Question is unclear. How can you setup an alarm on a dimension? Explain the problem with an example.

Comment: Say I have 4 dimension key/pair combinations. I would like to setup an alarm against the value of each individual dimension.

Comment: Still unclear. Can you edit your question giving some concrete examples of what you want to achieve?

Comment: If one dimension reaches a certain threshold or value, trigger the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A metric is identified by a set of dimensions and a namesapce. If you change a dimension value, well then you've created a new metric. You can only alarm on metric datapoint values.

See [CloudWatch Concepts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Dimension) for clarification.